# Error while inserting/Editing Sales Orders with Items with \ char as part of the InventoryID

Tags: system, acumatica, orders, ecommerce-sales

I am facing an issue while inserting Sales Orders to `Acumatica` via API for items that has the \ character as part of the InventoryID.

If I try to insert a Stack Overflow with an InventoryID \Adjustment, the API returns the following error:

```
PX.Data.PXFieldProcessingException: Error: An error occurred while 
processing the field Inventory ID : Error: 'Inventory ID' cannot be found in 
the system.. ---> PX.Data.PXSetPropertyException: Error: 'InventoryID' 
cannot be found in the system
```

However, the item does exist in the database.

Any suggestions of how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

"\" is an escape char in C#.    I would wager a bet that it's trying to treat it as that.

Try replacing the "\" with "\\" and see if that works.

You could also try specifying it as a literal with @ - @"My\ID" however seeing how this is submitted to the server for processing, I'd try the escape first

As a side note though, i would strongly recommend removing odd chars like that from the id's.